# Ext JS: Get calling function's name

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I'm curious to know if there's an Ext way of getting the calling function's name without having to use **arguments.callee.caller** (as that's been deprecated) and naming my functions. Let's say I have this code:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  enabled: true
});

Ext.define('Mixin', {
  logWarning: function logWarning() {
    console.log('warning: ' + this.$className + '::' + arguments.callee.toString());  // displays function logWarning() ...
    console.log('warning: '+ this.$className + '::' + arguments.callee.caller.toString());  // displays functions() ...
  }
});

Ext.define('My.Panel', {
  extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
  mixins: ['Mixin']
});

Ext.application({
  name: 'Test',
  launch: function() {
    Ext.define('MyPanel', {
      extend: 'My.Panel',
      width: 200,
      height: 300,
      initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent();
        this.logWarning();
      }
    });
    Ext.create('MyPanel', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
  }
});
```

In my **logWarning** function, the first console.log string shows me the function name because I named the function. However, in most Ext apps, the functions remain anonymous because there's no need, as I'm using the scope like **this.logWarning**, and it doesn't make sense to maintain the same two names in my code.

What I'd like to know is, is there a way of grabbing the calling function's name using some Ext function I'm unaware of? I can easily grab the className with **this.$className**, but I'm sure that's frowned upon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to skirtle over on the [Sencha Forums](https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?290913-Get-calling-function-name&p=1062878&viewfull=1#post1062878), I ended up using `arguments.callee.caller.$name`.  It's not ideal, but it currently gets the job done... when/if it gets deprecated, I'll have to revisit this issue.

**EDIT**

This was written a long time ago, and I have since stopped using this property.  Instead, I'm throwing an error and parsing the stack trace to get the method, as the original answer wasn't doing what I needed.

Comment: Please be sure to, in some way, [credit skirtle](https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?290913-Get-calling-function-name&p=1062878&viewfull=1#post1062878) with the answer you provided here.